# How to use a function with integers to return images? (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, int

In one of my PHP pages for my website, I am trying to use a function to return a string, with three integers for the arguments. The strings in files 1 & 2 are for the same thing (One is name, the other is link). I've got something similar to this:
File1:

```
<?php
    return array("Str0", "Str1");
?>
```

File2:

```
<?php
    return array("http://example.com/Link0.png", "http://example.com/Link1.png");
?>
```

File3:

```
<?php
    $names = include 'file1.php';
    $links = include 'file2.php';
    function imgsrc($int1, $int2, $int3){
        return '<img title="'.$names[$int1].'" src="'.$links[$int1].'" /><img src="http://example.com/img.png" />';
    }
?>
```

I have 5 images there. Images 2 and 4 are always the same, images 1, 3, and 5 are most of the time different, depending on the arguments I put. I echo the function out like this:

```
echo imgsrc(0, 0, 1);
```

I repeat that every time I want to have the 5 images, yet it only shows boxes. The HTML when I press F12 in the site only shows this:

```
<img src="" width="40px" height="40px" title="">
```

I'm trying to get it to show images with the title.

Comment: Why do you need a `string` and not an `integer` ? I'm not following your question...specially the title ***"How to use a function to return a string with integers? "*** You may want to rephrase it.

Comment: On File2; there is **no file extension like .jpg or .png** or did you just omit that part? If the image does not have an extension name; i doubt that you may have any image displayed on your page.

Comment: The return value is a string, but the arguments are integers. I am echoing out a string, not an integer.

Comment: No, in the actual code, it has .png. These are just examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. Instead of using integers, I used another file with arrays and used those ints to get the array value of the original files.